# No such file or directory?

Tags: command-line, files, mv

Im installing SquirrelMail in Ubuntu Server 18.04. I got it from here:

```
wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/squirrelmail/files/stable/1.4.22/squirrelmail-webmail-1.4.22.zip
```

Then I unzipped using `unzip squirrelmail-webmail-1.4.22.zip`, then when I try to move it inside the web server with `mv squirrelmail-webmail-1.4.22 /var/www/html/` it says

```
 mv: cannot move 'squirrelmail-webmail-1.4.22' to '/var/www/html/': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Verify what has been unzipped via `ls` in the directory where you did `unzip`. The unzipped files don't necessarily have to have same name as the zip archive.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the output of the command `ls` for the relevant folders to prove your statements “it exists”. Don’t forget to apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) for the pasted terminal text.

Comment: The current version of *squirrelmail* which you want to install is from **2011**. I would **not** recommend using a program that old if connected to the internet. Better use something similar, e.g. *roundcube*. See [list of Vulnerabilities](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-803/product_id-1366/Squirrelmail-Squirrelmail.html).

Answer (score 2):

Check that the `/var/www/html/` directory exists. `/var/www/html/` is standard directory to use for a web server like apache or nginx.

Use `sudo` to avoid permissions issues.

```
sudo mv -v squirrelmail-webmail-1.4.22 /var/www/html/
```

If your user is root then there is no issue, but if user is not root then you face this kind of error.

```
mv: cannot move 'squirrelmail-webmail-1.4.22.zip' to '/var/www/html/squirrelmail-webmail-1.4.22.zip': Permission denied
```

If `/var/www/html/` does not exist, you can create that directory manually.

Furthermore installation:

```
cd /var/www/html/
sudo unzip squirrelmail-webmail-1.4.22.zip
sudo cat squirrelmail-webmail-1.4.22/doc/INSTALL
```

Follow this documentation for the installation. I have done the installation according to this, and it is working on my Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, the directory was not there because I didn't install the Apache server, after I did it, the directory was there, it was a rookie mistake, for I'm rookie, sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Comment: Well, congrats on resolving the issue, which turned out to be fairly simple, which is always a good thing